# Keyboard doesn't work in X11 after resuming from sleep/suspend

Tags: debian, keyboard, suspend, mate-desktop, screen-lock

### My computer:

- Debian 8.3
- Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Dell Latitude 5420

I'm using `XMonad` window manager, some applets (in `stalonetray`) from mate desktop (nm-applet, power-manager applet) and `i3lock` for locking the screen.

### Problem:

Usually everything works fine when resuming from sleep/hibernation/suspend, but sometimes after resuming from sleep, I enter the password which unlock the screen (i3lock), desktop content appears and I can move the mouse (both external USB and internal touchpad and trackpoint) - but keyboard (both laptop's builtin and external USB) doesn't work.

When this happens:

- the keyboard itself works - the CAPSLOCK/NUMLOCK leds reacts to pressing CapsLock or NumLock keys
- I can switch to console (CTRL-ALT-F1) and keyboard works in console and I can go back to X11 using (ALT-F7)
- but in X11, nothing reacts to keypresses
- pulling keyboard's USB connector out and back in doesn't help
- when I suspend the laptop again (from console) and resume, the `mate`'s screen locker appears but the keyboard still doesn't work.

### What I tried:

My only solution is to manually kill `mate-session`, `mate-power-manager` or `mate-screensaver` from console and then the keyboard works in X11 again.

I think that perhaps mate-power-manager tries to lock the screen after I unlock it with i3lock, but somehow doesn't display itself..

### The question:

What can I do to prevent `mate-*` components from locking the screen or blocking the keyboard (assuming I'm correct)?

Comment: If you take i3lock out of the equation, do you still have this problem? From a text console, run `DISPLAY=:0 xinput list`, is the output different in normal operation and when you have the problem? Still from a text console, run `DISPLAY=:0 xev` and switch back to X then type a few keys, does `xev` report `KeyPress` events?

Comment: @Gilles ok, that's a good idea (xev, xinput) - as for i3lock - it's hard to tell, because as I've said in the question - the problem is not 100% reproducible - it happens only sometimes, and I have no idea what triggers it (except for some murphy's law - it often happens when I open the laptop to show something to my superiors :) or generaly when it's most annoying). Anyway - thanks for the comment, it's definitely helpful

Comment: have you tried this https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152185 ?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi I "solved" (i.e. it hasn't happened again...yet)  this by disabling `mate-power-manager` - which is not the best solution, but I can live without it. I do not think it's a i8042 problem - but if it will happen again, I could try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a half solution in https://superuser.com/a/1106756/632116

You can try to plug a new USB device on the USB hub where keyboard connected to. That article said do this could make the keyboard works back to normal.

### UPDATE 2017-10

This issue had gone after I changed my keyboard to another new one.